# Columns within columned 960.gs div

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

Suppouse I have a div that is member of 960.gs style grid. It has icon and text. Now I want the text to be indented from the icon, however I can't use a grid because I am in one already and because I'll have many divs like this one and each icon and text should stick to parent's top.

```
<div id="I_AM_GRID_MEMBER">
<span class="icon"><img src="lala.png"></span>
<span>Some text here </span><br/>
<span>Some text here </span><br/>
<span>Some text here </span><br/>
<span>Some text here </span><br/>
</div>

.icon{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: 73px;
height: 56px;
background-color: black;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q6ZbH/2/
The question is: how can I indent my text, so it won't really float around the icon?

Sorry for complex explanation, it's quite hard to explain in words what you want to achieve visually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CSS image background on the containing DIV and give it enough padding to push the text away from the icon.

```
#I_AM_GRID_MEMBER {
     background-image:url(/lala.png);
     padding-top: 56px;
     padding-left:73px`enter code here`
}
```